# Deduction of the function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction

Let's say we have a class template like this:

```
template<typename F>
class A
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  A(F f, Args... args)
  { /* Do something... */ }
};
```

And now I want to use it in some way like this one:

```
A<int(int)> a(::close, 1);
```

Now the question: is there any way to omit the `<int(int)>` because a compiler can know this information for the `::close`? There is no need to save the "design" of the template.

As for concrete task, I need to design a template of a class. Objects of this class could take a function and parameters for this function at construction time and call this function later.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, you (currently) cannot. The standard way of doing this is by creating "make_like" function (such as [`make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair), [`make_optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) ...):

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
A<std::decay_t<F>> make_A (F &&f, Args&&... args) {
    return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

C++17 will introduce [template argument deduction for class](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r2.html) which will allow you to do exactly what you want (see also [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228754/2666289) below).

Comment: I believe the proper way to make those factory functions is to use `std::decay` or a similar trait on `A<F>`. Which would make it `A<std::decay_t<F>>`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional or other `make_*` reference

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yes you are right, if I use universal references I should be using `std::decay`, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question, and therefore the answer. Is the whole goal to be able to say `auto a(::close, 1)`?

Comment: @Assimilater OP's ask a way to automatically deduced class template parameter when constructing an instance (e.g. `A(::close, 1)`) which is not possible in c++14. The above answer allows you to deduce the template parameter using the `make_A` function, e.g. `auto a = make_A(::close, 1)` or `f(make_A(::close, 1))`.

Comment: Yes, that is the wording of the OP....maybe the wording is just confusing to me because I haven't done much with variadic templates....is this a direct consequence of that only? It seemed like it could apply more generally...

Comment: @Assimilater No, this is not a consequence of variadic templates. See `std::pair`, you cannot do `std::pair a(1, 1)` or `std::pair(1, 1)` because class template argument cannot be deduced so  you use `std::make_pair(1, 1)` to have `T1` and `T2` deduced.

Comment: @Holt Ah, sorry that took a bit to click, thanks for the exp :)

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to the adoption of template parameter deduction for constructors, in C++17, you'll be able to just write:

```
A a(::close, 1);
```

Before that, you'll just need to write a factory to do the deduction for you:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
A<std::decay_t<F>> make_a(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

auto a = make_a(::close, 1);
```

This is a little verbose, but at least you don't need to worry about efficiency - there will be no copies made here thanks to RVO.

Comment: Re: C++17: That is so weird. It seems like you should at least have to write `A<auto> a(::close,1);`. Though I guess I'll get used to it . . .

Answer (score 11):

You cannot omit the arguments of a template class, unless they are defaulted. What you can do is have a maker function which deduces the argument and forwards this argument to the template class, returning an object of the appropriate instantiation.

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
A<F> make_A(F f, Args&&... args) {
    return A<F>(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```